# How did Dr. Zoidberg get his degree in medicine?

Tags: futurama, zoidberg

Dr. Zoidberg is a terrible doctor. How did he manage to pass his course?

Answer (score 7):

Zoidberg does not actually have a medical degree - his doctorate is in art history, which was revealed in the fifth episode of the sixth season, ["The Duh-Vinci Code"](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/The_Duh-Vinci_Code).